# Cat throwing litter out of box!

Tags: cats, toilet-training

My cat throws her litter way out of her box. I've used mats, newspaper, and AstroTurf, but she manages to fling it way beyond even that. She won't use a covered box either. It doesn't matter if the litter is fresh or a few days old. She does the same thing, and sometimes she digs and doesn't even use the box. It's like she's digging just to dig! I really have no idea how to break her of this behavior and any input would help! How can I stop this behavior?